# C++ Clearing Memory from Dynamic Arrays - Memory Won't Clear

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, stack, malloc

I read articles on cplusplus.com, tutorialspoint.com, codecall.net post, and different posts here on Stack Overflow.

I also emailed my professor who after I explained that the material wasn't in the book and not part of the assigned chapter, his response was *"I am well aware that this material is not in the chapter. I expect students to be able to do research. Try using google to search for pointers and malloc to create dynamic arrays. I get 1,600,000 hits."*

**HERE IS MY ASSIGNMENT:**

> Use an STL stack to reverse a line of input characters that are read into a string.  Your stack should contain the characters of the user's string.  Use getline() for input – it needs to be part of your C++ tool inventory.
>
> A note on getline:  Suppose I am doing the following -
>
> ```
> This program reverses a string using the STL stack
> Enter your string of less than 80 characters followed by an ENTER
> a string input
> Enter another? 1 = continue. Anything else to stop
> 1
> Enter your string of less than 80 characters followed by an ENTER
> a second string
> ```
>
> This code will not work by simply using the following loop:
>
> ```
> int go = 1;
> cout << "This program reverses a string using the STL stack" << endl;
> while(go == 1){
>     cout << "Enter your string of less than 80 characters followed by an ENTER" << endl;
>     char* s = (char *)malloc(80);
>     cin.getline(s,81,'\n');
>     cout << s << endl;
>     cout << "Enter another? 1 = continue. Anything else to stop" << endl;
>     cin >> go;
> }
> ```
>
> Try it and see what happens!  Also note that I never got rid of the memory I allocated with malloc – your code must get rid of it. Also, malloc outside the loop for more efficient code.
>
> You must use a getchar() (part of the cstdio library) after cin >> go;
>
> The reason is that when you enter 1 you also use the Enter key.  This is still in the buffer when you hit getline again!  So you will read in '\n'
>
> Also note that when you get something off of the STL stack you must use .top() to look at it followed by .pop() to remove it.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> This program reverses a string using the STL stack
> Enter your string of less than 80 characters followed by an Enter
> m&m cheeto mayo
> oyam oteehc m&m
> Enter another? 1 = continue. Anything else to stop
> 1
> Enter your string of less than 80 characters followed by an Enter
> celery lettuce apple
> elppa ecuttel yrelec
> Enter another? 1 = continue. Anything else to stop
> 0
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

**HERE ARE THE THINGS I'VE TRIED:**
Using **malloc()** in and outside the loop.
Using both **free()** and **delete()** in and outside the loop.
Trying to make a temporary new pointer, then reassign my old pointer to the temp pointer.

I've been using repl.it to do this assignment so would that be a possibility of why this isn't working?

After I continually run the program it looks the memory doesn't clear. It just appears to add on the characters to what I had type during the last iteration.

I hope that I covered enough of the criteria from this post (http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). I apologize if I don't.

Any help would be appreciated. If you want to provide me links to sites, or possibly other topics to research/google to help I'm all ears.

My source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int go = 1;
    cout << "This program reverses a string using the STL stack" << endl;
    char* s = (char *)malloc(80);   
    char *temp;
    stack <char> reverse;   


    while(go == 1){

        cout << "Enter your string of less than 80 characters followed by an ENTER" << endl;
        cin.getline(s,81,'\n');

      for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++){
        reverse.push(s[i]); 
      }
    for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++){
        cout << reverse.top();
        reverse.pop();
      }

    char *temp = (char*)realloc(s, 81*sizeof(char));     
    if ( temp != NULL )
    {
    s = temp;
    }
    else
    {
    free(s);
    }

        cout << "\nEnter another? 1 = continue. Anything else to stop" << endl;
        cin >>go;
        getchar();
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**HERE IS MY OUTPUT:**

```
This program reverses a string using the STL stack
Enter your string of less than 80 characters followed by an ENTER
 Joey
yeoJ
Enter another? 1 = continue. Anything else to stop
 1

Enter your string of less than 80 characters followed by an ENTER
 Dog
goD
Enter another? 1 = continue. Anything else to stop
 1

Enter your string of less than 80 characters followed by an ENTER
 JoeyDog
goDyeoJ
Enter another? 1 = continue. Anything else to stop
 1

Enter your string of less than 80 characters followed by an ENTER
 lkjlkdjf;ldjaflkdjaflkdjlfajdlkfja;sdlkjf
fjklds;ajfkldjafljdklfajdklfajdl;fjdkljkl
Enter another? 1 = continue. Anything else to stop
 1

Enter your string of less than 80 characters followed by an ENTER
 joey
fjklds;ajfkldjafljdklfajdklfajdl;fjdyeoj
Enter another? 1 = continue. Anything else to stop
```

Comment: In both code snippets you allocate `80` bytes, but then tell `getline` to read up to *81* characters into that memory. Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead.

Comment: That's what the professor had so I assumed that was right. Is that what is causing the memory not to clear?

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition. Multiplying by `sizeof (char)` is pointless.

Comment: Your question lacks a clear problem description. I have no idea what you mean by "clearing memory".

Comment: I assume when I clear the memory for the array that it is then a blank array, but when I rerun the loop all the original information is still there?

Comment: What do you mean by "clear the memory"?

Comment: By clear I mean get rid of the memory. That's what the assignment said so that's what I assumed free() did, but that didn't work.

Comment: "didn't work" is not a problem description. Also, there is no such thing as a "blank array". Please post the actual output of your code, not your interpretation of what's going on.

Comment: Your assignment does not use the word "clear" anywhere AFAICS.

Comment: Your code doesn't even call `free` (unless `realloc` fails, but that's really unlikely).

Comment: What do you mean by the term "clearing" in "clearing the memory"? I would assume "clearing" meant set every byte to `0`, but you don't do that. Also, don't ever use `malloc` in C++. It's a bad habit. Use `new[]` instead. For now, until you learn about `std::vector` or `std::string` when you should use only those.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I bet the constraints of the assignment don't allow a sensible solution. :-/

Comment: Further to that, the run up to 81, besides being off-by-one, doesn't account for the scenario of someone entering a line with exactly what the description days: *less* than 80 chars. It could be one char, two, seventy-nine, etc. Honestly, your professors code is only slightly more terrible than his instructions. Ex: read an extra char to consume the newline. What if someone entered a space, or another char before hitting enter? The proper solution tests io operations (of which there is zero in his code), and consume *thru* the newline after successfully acquiring `go`.

Comment: We're allocating a fixed (and small) buffer for the line, so there's zero reason to use either `malloc` or `new[]` here. This could simply be a local array.

Comment: Melpomene - I fully agree with you.

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: There is a programming concept called [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) that may help you. TL;DR, The idea is to explain every operation you perform to the duck. If you cannot explain what you are doing and why you are doing it to the duck, you need to rethink what you are doing.

Comment: If I enter the word "dog" i get "god" as expected, but then if I enter "moon" during the next loop I now get "godnoom". I'm expecting that "getting rid" og the memory clears the array. Is that what I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: You're still paraphrasing instead of posting the actual output of your program.

Comment: I've added the output to my post. It's at the bottom. I apologize for paraphrasing. It works at first, but then after a while you see that some of the old words get added to my input.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to clear memory. Better way is to check length of string. Corrected version of main loop (I removed some less important elements like cout for clarity):

```
cin.getline(s,80,'\n');
int len = strlen(s);

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    reverse.push(s[i]); 
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    cout << reverse.top();
    reverse.pop();
}
```

So I count length of string with `strlen`, and I use the result in loops. Notice, I completely removed yout `temp` thing, as it has no sense now.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm just confusing getting rid of memory vs. What my array is doing. Most likely overthinking.